# How to solve error while installing pyqtwebengine

Tags: python, pyqt5, spyder

I installed spyder on my macbook without error. But when I called it, it said `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets'`. Then, I tried to installed pyqtwebengine by this command `pip install pyqtwebengine`. But an error appeared:

```
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0d/8d/aece7598d2959f66f09fcced6487dd7727f44ad867fc09978c5aeeaf1d29/PyQtWebEngine-5.15.0.tar.gz#sha256=670812688e40bf75f70ddf01eadd897d231300318d3856b275bf8e7e0085bf75 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pyqtwebengine/) (requires-python:>=3.5). Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/thienbinh/miniconda3/bin/python /Users/thienbinh/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/13/76vrjtyn2kgckfh7v76ndv900000gn/T/tmpvz4djx3v Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached PyQtWebEngine-5.14.0.tar.gz (47 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/thienbinh/miniconda3/bin/python /Users/thienbinh/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/13/76vrjtyn2kgckfh7v76ndv900000gn/T/tmpt3pekpi6
         cwd: /private/var/folders/13/76vrjtyn2kgckfh7v76ndv900000gn/T/pip-install-apjpo7q4/pyqtwebengine_b52b14a545e2480aacf917c524518ffe
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
    /Users/thienbinh/miniconda3/bin/qmake -query
    These bindings will be built: QtWebEngineCore, QtWebEngine, QtWebEngineWidgets.
    Generating the QtWebEngineCore bindings...
    _in_process.py: Unable to find file "QtCore/QtCoremod.sip"
    
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/47/9f/60e630711fd1dd14ef3bd95c86c733c86b8c0853749c7a03691f681f13fd/PyQtWebEngine-5.14.0.tar.gz#sha256=e11595051f8bfbfa49175d899b2c8c2eea3a3deac4141edf4db68c3555221c92 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pyqtwebengine/) (requires-python:>=3.5). Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/thienbinh/miniconda3/bin/python /Users/thienbinh/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/13/76vrjtyn2kgckfh7v76ndv900000gn/T/tmpt3pekpi6 Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyqtwebengine (from versions: 5.14.0, 5.15.0, 5.15.1, 5.15.2, 5.15.3, 5.15.4, 5.15.5)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyqtwebengine
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: what is your python version? How did you install pyqt?

Comment: it is Python 3.8.11. I pip to install pyqt:  pip install PyQt5

Comment: Try not using miniconda but the official python since I think that is the cause of the error (some miniconda bug). If you are going to use miniconda then use the conda packages.

Comment: Thank you. I actually use another important code. I could not install it successfully by anaconda, so I have to opt to miniconda.

Comment: Then 1. Uninstall pyqt5 2. Execute `conda install -c conda-forge pyqtwebengine` and `conda install -c conda-forge pyqt`

Comment: Sorry, but error still appears. PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels: - pyqtwebengine

Comment: See https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pyqtwebengine